# Getting the dynamic server name to a hyperlink

Tags: jsp, struts

I want to know what "`<%=pageContext.getRequest().getServerName()%`." returns in a JSP page. 
Actually I want to do the following.
Currently I am in "`https://eyedev.appspot.com/admin/login.do`" page. And i have hyperlink with a name as a hyperlink name to a page where it states the privacy policy."`https://eyedev.appspot.com/privacy.html`".. The server name is dynamic. (it can be eyelive.appspot.com also"..
So I want to know how I can get the dynamic link to the privacy policy page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contextPath in this case, like this.

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/privacy.html">Click Here </a>
```

or

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/privacy.html">Click Here </a>
```

Comment: Then, Replace "Click Here" with your label (may be "Privacy")